# Как отловить SQL запросы, которые выполняет pg-promise

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

Я использую [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) с подстановками, поэтому не знаю заранее что выполнится. Как мне увидеть исполняемые SQL запросы и залогировать их?

Т.е. например такой код:

```
db.query("select * from users where name=${name} and active=${active}", {name: 'John', active: true});
```

Как увидеть (и залогировать) то что выполнится уже со вставленными подстановками?
UPD: логировать нужно средствами nodejs

Comment: в yii примерно та же ситуация. в принципе если у вас  при ошибке в запросе он падает (или пишется в лог), то можно заведомо неправильный запрос составить и посмотреть ошибку `db.query("1select `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В библиотеке [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) все поддерживаемые события доступны через [опции инициализации библиотеки](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html).

В том числе событие [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query) как-раз и предоставляет все датали о выполняемых SQL-запросах.

И есть еще модуль [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), который автоматически показывает детали по всем событиям библиотеки [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), в оптимально отформатированном виде. Он тоже поддерживает логирование, и даже в более удобном виде, через событие [log](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor#log).

А еще вы можете подсмотреть результат форматирования не выполняя самого запроса, а через вызов `pgp.as.format(query, values)`, который и используется при форматировании запросов внутри самой библиотеки. Он просто вернет результирующию строку.

П.С. Я автор библиотеки [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), и если что, вы всегда можете задать мне вопрос на сайте проекта, но на английском ;)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. События query хороши, но опять таки всплывает проблема записи SQL выражения в лог нужного HTP-запроса. Тем не менее для отладки самое оно, точнее не query, а error - буду знать. Если не секрет как нашли этот вопрос? Вас же тут не было ))

Comment: Про monitor Не слышал и решил попробовать - мозгов не хватило запуститься, хочется хотя бы одни законченный пример. А вот format стал именно тем решением, которое мне нужно, благо мой low-load проект не пострадает от двойного конвертирования... хотя я могу сконвертить, а потом это выражение выполнить, ничего же не поломается?

Comment: Нашлось само собой, я автоматически вижу все запросы со ссылкой на библиотеку. [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) подключается [в пару строк](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor#usage), даже не знаю как еще упростить. Если вызывать `format` а результат передавать в запрос, то ничего не поломается, если причиной сбоя не является само форматирование, поэтому использование события `error` - это более надежно, оно все типы проблем поймает и сообщит в деталях.

Comment: Я эти пару строк видел. Только вопрос как он подключается, к чему, где запрос тестовый? Я про это ))

Comment: [Полный пример с использованием pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/examples/monitor.js).

Comment: @MiF - пример вам помог? Логирование заработало?

Comment: Спасибо большое за труд, пример целиком и полностью исчерпал мои вопросы

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430380/is-there-a-postgresql-equivalent-of-sql-server-profiler) подсказывают, что в PostgreSql можно использовать параметр конфигурации `log_statement` для логгирования запросов.

Comment: Не то. 1. Это нужно настраивать сервер БД 2. Не будет соответствия http-запрос - SQL-выражение, сложно потом в этой каше сопоставить что происходило (это ведь не обязательно ошибки)

Comment: @MiF Ну, в вопросе-то у Вас не было указано, что доступа к настройкам базы нет, и необходимо использовать именно средства node.js...

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение, поправил вопрос